# when assigning JSON data, not an array error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JSON data format.

```
{
"0": {
    "id": "1",
    "image": "/images/brands/surf_excel.png",
    "name": "Surf Excel",
    "productCount": "6"
},
"1": {
    "id": "2",
    "image": "/images/brands/rin.png",
    "name": "Rin",
    "productCount": "5"
},
"2": {
    "id": "3",
    "image": "/images/brands/ariel.png",
    "name": "Ariel",
    "productCount": "4"
}
}
```

When i am trying to assign this data like this..

```
$scope.Brands = [];
$scope.Brands = data; // Not an array error
```

Basically i want to assign data and access one by one.

How to fix this error?

Comment: your data is **NOT** an array, hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop for this

```
  angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
   $scope.Brands.push(value);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember, **Whenever there's an array, it would be surrounded by square brackets `[` `]`**.

Now you can see why your JSON data doesn't contain any array. Instead of just assigning JSON's data directly to `$scope.Brands`, you can push the values like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var data = JSON.parse('{"0":{"id":"1","image":"/images/brands/surf_excel.png","name":"Surf Excel","productCount":"6"},"1":{"id":"2","image":"/images/brands/rin.png","name":"Rin","productCount":"5"},"2":{"id":"3","image":"/images/brands/ariel.png","name":"Ariel","productCount":"4"}}');
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.Brands = [];
  
  angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
   $scope.Brands.push(value);
  })
  
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify($scope.Brands, 0, 8) + "</pre>");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"></body>

</html>
```

Now when you run this snippet, you'll see the data surrounded by `[` and `]`. This indicates that it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using angular, @SSH has already given the best answer. Another way to solve this is (non angular):

```
var brands = new Array();

//Get the keys and iterate through them and add each entry
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
    brands.push(data[key]);
});
```